# SwiftUI - Merge two different Paths into one OR change strokeStyle mid-drawing

Tags: swiftui, path, shapes

I have a vertical list of points that are connected with lines. Up to the so-called "active point", the lines should be solid and from the active point on dotted (metaphor for what the user already finished and what is still coming).

Here is how it looks on Android:

[image: android app screenshot]

It is one long path in the end, it just **changes style in the middle**. How can I combine these two into one?

I was imagining something like this:

```
func drawPaths(points: [CGPoint]) -> some Shape {
        let activeChlgIndex = (chlgViewModel.activeChallenge?.id ?? -1)
        var wholePath: Path
        
        // Before active challenge
        var solidPath =  Path { path in
            path.move(to: points[0])
            
            for (i, _) in points.enumerated() {
                if (i <= activeChlgIndex) {
                    path.addLine(to: points[i])
                }
            }
        }
        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
        .foregroundColor(.pathColorSolid)
        
        // After active challenge
        var dottedPath =  Path { path in
            path.move(to: points[activeChlgIndex])
            
            for (i, _) in points.enumerated() {
                if (i >= activeChlgIndex) {
                    path.addLine(to: points[i])
                }
            }
        }
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
        .foregroundColor(.pathColorDotted)
        
        wholePath = solidPath.addPath(dottedPath)
        
        return wholePath
    }
```

Comment: In SwiftUI you can join paths w/o color, applying color converts path in view.

Comment: @Asperi So I should create & inject them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end making them two separate paths was the easiest solution.

Color can only applied after the return of the function in body, because otherwise it's some `ColoredView<XYZ>` or so and cannot be returned as `any Shape`

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let points = calculatePoints(geometry: geometry)
                let activeChlgIndex = (chlgViewModel.activeChallenge?.id ?? -1) - 1
                drawSolidPaths(points: points, activeChlgIndex: activeChlgIndex)
                    .foregroundColor(.pathColorSolid)
                drawDottedPaths(points: points, activeChlgIndex: activeChlgIndex)
                    .foregroundColor(.pathColorDotted)
                drawCircles(geometry: geometry, points: points, activeChlgIndex: activeChlgIndex)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func drawSolidPaths(points: [CGPoint], activeChlgIndex: Int) -> some Shape {
        let pointsUpToActiveChlg = Array(points[0 ... activeChlgIndex])
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: pointsUpToActiveChlg[0])
            
            for (i, _) in pointsUpToActiveChlg.enumerated() {
                path.addLine(to: pointsUpToActiveChlg[i])
            }
        }
        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
    }
    
    func drawDottedPaths(points: [CGPoint], activeChlgIndex: Int) -> some Shape {
        let pointsFromActiveChlg = Array(points[activeChlgIndex ..< points.count])
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: pointsFromActiveChlg[0])
            
            for (i, _) in pointsFromActiveChlg.enumerated() {
                path.addLine(to: pointsFromActiveChlg[i])
            }
        }
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
    }
```